# USB tether android to laptop, use laptop as wifi router

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, router

I have unlimited tethering via usb, but not wifi via metro...  so can I tether my phone to the laptop (via usb) and use the laptop as a wifi router?  Virtual routers don't seem to be able to pick up on the "pda net modem" as a viable connection to share, and creating an adhoc isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the $60 dollar plan with metro your wasting your time with Pda. If your phone can hot spot use. Metro will not charge you anymore for this at the higher price. I did it. You'll get messages that say otherwise.....ignore them...there's a disclosure that now states they no longer charge for Hotspot on the 60 dollars plan.

Comment: I do have the $60 plan, however the wifi is so throttled after I get the message that I've "used it all", that it makes it worthless to use.  I've found Connectify that is working great for my purposes.   Thanks for the reply.